# Linq with a dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq database function which worked fine, however changes had to be made to the types holding certain bits of infomation outside of my control.

The currect situation is I have an asp.net 3.5 site, with infomation stored in a dictionary.

the code I have was

```
Table.Insert(_rules.RuleList
                     .Where(rule => !ruleRecords
                            .Any(r => r.RuleID == rule.RuleID)
             ));
```

As you can see it excludes where r.RuleID == rule.RuleID

All good, however 'r' is no longer an object, and is now a dictionary.

Any Ideas how I can get the value of the dictionary, by providing the key ("RuleID") inside the linq query?

Any suggestions greatly appreciated, however I can not update to 4.0 and I cant have the data not stored in an object, unless it can be a temporary conversion

Comment: where do you have your IDs stored ? You will probably want to join the list of IDs to the dictionary based on a common field. Can you add more information on what data you've got in the dictionary

Comment: You mean , the ruleRecords is now a Dictionary? if so does the key in that Dictionary correspond to the RuleId of rule? If so try this, r => r.Key == rule.RuleID

Comment: Just to be picky... lol - A Dictionary (instance) *is* and object.

Comment: ha haa, thats true @EtherDragon, not picky at all

Comment: @DivHenr Im just getting 'cannot resolve symbol "key"'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the key of your dictionary is `RuleId`, I think you can re-write this as:

```
Table.Insert(_rules.RuleList.Where(rule => !ruleRecords.ContainsKey(rule.RuleId))
```

Comment: Iv accepted this as the answer, as this is correct, however I had to do something slightly different (see my edit)

Answer (score 1):

What your asked for (how to get the value in a dict, providing a key): `dict[key]`, so in your case `r[rule.RuleID]`

As was pointed out in another answer what you probably want is: Dictionary.[ContainsKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/kw5aaea4.aspx)